Build JSON array in the request body in SharePoint Designer 2013
Below is the request body which I wish to use POST method with call HTTP web service action:
{
   "fields": {
      "project": {
         "key": "key-content"
      },
      "components": [
         {
            "name": "component A"
         }
      ]
}

I created a "fields" dictionary with "project" (type: dictionary) and "components".
For "project", I created another sub-dictionary as below:



Name
Type
Value




key
String
key-content



However, for "components", I cannot successfully create the JSON payload with array type.
I've tried to set the value in dictionary as below but failed.



Name
Type
Value




project
Dictionary
(project sub-dictionary created above)


components
String
[{"name": "component A"}]



It seems that the JSON payload passed to portal will be like:
{
   "fields": {
      "project": {
         "key": "key-content"
      },
      "components": "[{"name": "component A"}]"
}

I would like to know if it is possible to remove double quotation mark before and after the array or is there any better way to deal with this situation.
Thank you so much for your time and assistance.
